# Is there a shortcut to force close an application?

Tags: 11.04, unity, indicator

Back in 10.10, I was able to force close an application by clicking the force close icon on the panel on top. Now, with Unity, I am not able to add new icons on the panel. So is there like a keyboard shortcut to force close an application?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

right click on desktop

create launcher

name : xkill

command : xkill

click ok

double click to launch. drag to quicklaunch bar on left to launch from there...

you could even change the icon to the original icon by right click + properties, then click on the springboard icon picture which will take you to a browse window(choose an icon). Now navigate to the following folder  /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps  and then find the icon named : gnome-panel-force-quit.svg, select it and voila.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a shortcut to the command `xkill`.