# Can't close chromium window

Tags: freeze, chromium

My desktop view is taken up completely by a frozen window from the chromium browser and I cannot manage to close it, switch windows, bring up the launcher or minimize it.

How can I resolve this without rebooting or losing my session?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/41740/18612

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up a terminal and then use `killall chromium-browser`.

If that doesn't work you should be able to get to a TTY with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Use the killall command there and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back.

Answer (score 4):

You can try running `xkill` in either the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> dialog or from a terminal, then just click Chromium.

That should force it to close.